# Something like this.getelementbyid(id of element inside this div)

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am looking for way to change 'GetElementById' div inside the div, which I am targeting.

Here's the example:

Let's say I have this

```
<div onclick="runscript()">
 <div id="insider">  
 </div> 
</div> 
<div onclick="runscript()">  
 <div id="insider">  
 </div> 
</div>
<script>
function runscript(){
document.getElementById('insider').style.color='red';
}
</script>
```

If I would like to change exactly the same div, which I am clicking on, I could use `this.style.color='red'`, but I need to change "insider" div inside exactly 'this' div I'm clicking on.

I am looking only for javascript solution, no jquery.

Comment: try to use querySelector

Comment: You cannot use the same id twice. It's supposed to be unique. `document.getElementById` only returns the first id it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div onclick="runscript(this)">
 <div class="insider">  
 </div> 
</div> 
<div onclick="runscript(this)">  
 <div class="insider">  
 </div> 
</div>
<script>
function runscript(object){
object.querySelector('.insider').style.color='red';
}
</script>
```

like in the comments above

- id is an unique identifier - so it is not valid to have an id twice in your DOM
- I recommend you to use addEventListener instead of the onclick attribute

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onclick="runscript(this)">
   <div class="insider">  
        Sample text
   </div> 
</div>
```

Give the insider div a `class` name called `insider` and do this:

```
function runscript(object){
    object.querySelector("div[class='insider']").style.color='red';
}
```

This works by passing the parent div to the `runscript` function with the keyword `this`. Then `querySelector` will try to find the element based upon the selector `div[class='insider']`. If found it will set the color of the text to red.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle in pure javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/53bnhscm/8/

HTML:

```
<div onclick="runscript(this);">
    <div class="insider"></div>
</div>
<div onclick="runscript(this);">
    <div class="insider"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
}
.insider {
    border: 3px solid green;
    height: 20px;  
}
```

Javascript:

```
function runscript(x) {
    x.firstElementChild.style.border = '1px solid red';
}
```